# Is there a way to execute EJBs outside an app server?

Tags: java, ejb, containers

EJB are like fishes that can't live outside the ocean of features provided by application servers.

But at certain times, I don't need all the features of an app server: the only thing I need is an EJB container and nothing else.

Because it's like using an ocean (JBoss, Websphere) or a lake (Glassfish) when all my fish needs is a small bowl of water (EJB container).

In short, is there way to run EJBs using Java EE exclusively? A virtual/local container perhaps?

Take JAX-WS: it provides the EndPoint class that allows you to publish without any application server at all. It greatly simplies the barrier to learning: allows you to drive right in without the need to setup anything or download additional jars.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[OpenEJB](http://openejb.codehaus.org/) is a small, embeddable EJB container that just might fit the bill of what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks Perception. I've come across some reading that in EJB 3.2, there's a movement to include an embedded EJB container that may actually be the one I'm looking for. But I haven't seen any resource that actually provides concrete details about it. For now, it appears OpenEJB is the closest incarnation of my hunt and for this, I accept your answer. Thank you.